# iOS 7 UISearchDisplayController issue

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Guys I am using UISearchDisplayController in my app and it was working fine in iOS 6 and 5. In iOS 7 I am getting this UI issue.[image]

The searchbar and the table view is going up a bit also the rows in the table are moving up more than the expected bounds. Any one facing the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set the property edgesForExtendedLayout of the UITableViewController to UIRectEdgeNone for iOS 7 and above to none because by default it's UIRectEdgeAll.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) 
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Some explication with the Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html).

Comment: Thanks I figured the same.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue, and setting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` doesn't work for me. One difference is that I'm using a `UIViewController` rather than `UITableViewController`.

Comment: With `UIViewController` I use a trick with a subview and the delta for iOS 6/7.
Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226751/ios7-iphone-5-giving-white-space-at-the-top