# ios7 - iPhone 5 giving white space at the top

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

Client has come back to me on projects saying they see white space on the top (they can't see the default things like time, wifi signal, etc) at the top.

This is happening when they installed iOS7 on their iPad.

Any idea why this is happening?

**Note:**

I have navigation bar as image. I hide the navigation bar and put navigation bar as an image.

---

**Downvoters**

I know this is not a perfect question for SO, but I thought to ask to take inputs. Tomorrow I am going to study on it.

Comment: see my SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953509/how-to-prevent-navigation-bar-from-covering-top-of-view-in-ios-7/18953585#18953585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to insert following code into your viewDidLoad:

```
if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)] ) {
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Otherwise you could try it, by removing the `UIStatusBar`. Select your Project, go to the section `General` and select `Hide during application launch` inside the subsection `Deployment Info`. Next you have to add the attribute inside the `Info` section called `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set it to NO.

Comment: are you telling me to hide status bar? you meant full screen app? well my answer is NO, as client have already mentioned that they wanna see status bar at the top...

Comment: the first snippet won't fade out the statusbar. And it will always be accessible even it is not visible. But of course if your clients want the status bar the last hint isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the status bar.

In your XIB or Storyboard chose to view your xib as iOS 6 :

[image]

On your view, add a Content View (you will add your outlets elements inside this content view) and add a Y delta of 20 (for the status bar) :

[image]

Now, if you compile your app on iOS 7 or iOS 6, your view will go up or down and you won't have the space anymore.

Comment: ok, so this won't happen with storyboards? Or same thing is also applicable for storyboard too?

Comment: I don't really know, I don't use storyboard. Try it for one view and tell us :)

Comment: sorry to bother.. what is content view? I am using xcode 4.6... I didn't find any content view... you meant normal view with nothing in it?

Comment: it's only a UIView that you add inside your view (but, I use this with XCode 5)